# Using jQuery delegate on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am unable to use delegate() in Internet explorer 8. It just does not recognise the event at all. It works in Firefox like a charm. I have heard some people say that they can get it to work by re-ordering their code, but hoping someone can give advice:

```
// REMOVING PRODUCTS:
            $("#items").delegate("img","click",function() {      
               var prodID = $(this).attr("name");
               // REMOVE PURCHASED ICON:
               var className = $("#gameImg area[name='"+prodID+"']").attr("id");
               $("."+className).remove();
               if(haveProduct(prodID) === true) {
                    // REMOVE FROM ARRAY:
                    var arrPos = $.inArray(prodID, productsAdded);
                    productsAdded.splice(arrPos,1);
                    addCash(prodID);
                    buildItems();
               } else {
                   alert("You have not purchased this product.");
               }
            });
```

Comment: use `bind()` or `live()` if suitable

Comment: does the developer tool's console come up with any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by looking for CSS issues :) The dynamic content created's position was not correct with the mouse cursor, hence when I tried to click on it it did not work.